# Why a C++ bitset initialized using an string is reversed?

Tags: c++, string, bit, bitsets

For the first time, I initialized a bit set using a string and found out that the bits are stored in reverse order, i.e.:

```
bitset<3> test(string("001"));
```

then the bits are stored as bellow:
    test[0] = 1
    test[1] = 0
    test[2] = 0

I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is the way it should be.

Comment: That's how bits are usually numbered: the bit on the right side is bit zero, because its value is 2^0. The second bit from the right is bit one because its value is 2^1. And so on.

Comment: In other words, it isn't reversed. The 0th bit is set to 1, the rest to 0, and the indexing respects that convention.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize it in reversed order?

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear what you are asking". You ask why something is that isn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Then I don't understand why in your first comment you would answer a question which you think is unclear?

Comment: It is not unclear. It is a non-question: "**Why a C++ bitset initialized using an string is reversed?**". It is not reversed, so there is no why.

Comment: If I initialize something with "001" and get "100" when I print it, for example, I would say it is in reverse order.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way it should be.  Bits stored in a bitset are ordered in such a way so that the index of a bit is the factor it is raised by.

In other words, the value at `test[0]` is the 2^0 bit, `test[1]` is 2^1, `test[2]` is 2^2, etc.

Endianness has nothing to do with it.